# how to set up language version on base of country Code

Tags: php

I would like to ask for advice. I have request to set up my website to redirect to language of the user.

The default language of web-page is `CZ`.

And the request is , if somebody visit website, who is not from `CZ`, then open `EN Version`.

first I find out from IP address the code of country.

And after I know the country Code I wanted to setup condition:

```
   if ($countryCODE == 'CZ') {

   } else { 
      echo '<script>location.href="?&EN"</script>'; 
   }
```

But obviously I got cycled.

How is the best way to solve it?

Another condition is that if a non-`CZ` user decides to switch to `Czech Version`, he needs to be able to browse `CZ Version` even if his `countryCode` is not `CZ`.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487171/how-to-make-a-multilanguage-website

Comment: I would recommend https://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-php/